# Can not make XMLHttpRequest to 3 separate API urls

Tags: javascript, api, xmlhttprequest

Before I start, here is the API. Super simple: https://www.cryptonator.com/api

To note, I have worked with api before, but i used a await async function, but for some reason I couldn't get that to work....but I found a tutorial for doing this with XML http request, so I decided to just move forwards doing it in XML because I was able to make a simple Bitcoin ticker.

I am building a simple widget to display the prices of Bitcoin, Litecoin, and Ethereum using the cryptonator API. Like I said above, I made a bitcoin ticker with the first function ( see code below ), and it works great. However, I am having issues trying to get 3 different currencies.

Here is what I am trying to do.

```
var url = "https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/btc-usd";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    parseJson(json);
  }
};

xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function parseJson(json) {

  var usdValue = json["ticker"]["price"];
  document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = usdValue;

  var usdValue = usdValue.replace(/[^\d.\-]/g, "");
  var usd = parseFloat(usdValue);
  document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = "$ " + usd.toFixed(2);
}



// 
// 

var xmlhttp2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url2 = "https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/ltc-usd";

xmlhttp2.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      parseJson(json);
    }
  };

  xmlhttp2.open("GET", url2, true);
  xmlhttp2.send();

  function parseJson(json) {

    var LTCusdValue = json["ticker"]["price"];
    // document.getElementById("data2").innerHTML = LTCusdValue;

    var LTCusdValue = LTCusdValue.replace(/[^\d.\-]/g, "");
    var LTCusd = parseFloat(LTCusdValue);
    document.getElementById("data2").innerHTML = "$ " + LTCusd.toFixed(2);
  }


//   
// 
// 

var xmlhttp3 = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url3 = "https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/eth-usd";

xmlhttp3.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      parseJson(json);
    }
  };

  xmlhttp3.open("GET", url3, true);
  xmlhttp3.send();

  function parseJson(json) {

    var ETHusdValue = json["ticker"]["price"];
    // document.getElementById("data3").innerHTML = ETHusdValue;

    var ETHusdValue = ETHusdValue.replace(/[^\d.\-]/g, "");
    var ETHusd = parseFloat(ETHusdValue);
    document.getElementById("data3").innerHTML = "$ " + ETHusd.toFixed(2);
  }
```

As you can see, I am trying to make 3 request to 3 different APis, but it isn't working. If I comment out all but one of these functions, it works fine. My issues comes when i try to use all 3 at once. If i use Bitcoin and Litecoin only, it will actually work, but will just break again once I try to use the 3rd function ( to get ethereum price ).

Comment: The first `xmlhttp` variable seems to be missing. Other than that your requests seem to work fine. Do you get any errors?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier thanks for pointing that out. It was a copy and paste mistake on my end. I will update my post showing that missing variable, 

As for errors,  the following happens.

As you see I am trying to apply each response ( price ) to a div ( data, data2, data3 for Bitcoin, Litecoin, and Ethereum respectfully ). For some reason, when I try to run all 3, only the 'data3' div will display its correct value only after flashing the BTC and LTC prices inside. I am not sure why it would do this, as I specifically tell each response where to go ( each data div ).

Comment: It probably is because you define the `parseJson` function three times. So every request uses the third `parseJson` function which outputs them all in `#data3`. See if that makes any difference.

Comment: That is great to hear. I've published my solution I suggested in the comments below. Feel free to accepted it as an answer if it helps you out.

Comment: @ETHan please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `parseJson` function is defined three times. This means that every time you write the function it will overwrite the previous definition. So in your case only the last `parseJson` function will be used for **all three** requests. You could do a couple of things.

### Write three different variations. (Bad practice)

Though this would be the less favorable of the options. It will require you to have repeated code copied multiple times. This can be done more efficiently.

```
function parseJson1(json) {
  ...
}

function parseJson2(json) {
  ...
}

function parseJson3(json) {
  ...
}
```

### Add an argument to the function. (Good practice)

Give the `parseJson` function a second argument that selects the element to output the value. This should be the `id` of the element you'll want to select.
This is the better solution because it only requires you to write a function once and call it multiple times accounting for the variations.

```
function parseJson(json, id) {
  var output = document.getElementById(id); // Select the element based on the id.
  if (output === null) { // If element is not found, stop the function.
    return;
  }
  var price = json["ticker"]["price"];
  var usdValue = price.replace(/[^\d.\-]/g, "");
  var usd = parseFloat(usdValue);
  output.innerHTML = "$ " + usd.toFixed(2);
}
```

The last technique is applicable to the rest of your code. Be aware of repeating yourself. You'll write much cleaner and *better* code when you only have to write something once.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to write an async wrapper function for this using a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).. This will allow you to use `async`/`await` with `XHR`..

To make using `XHR` a lot easier, you can use the built in [`fetch API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).. According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API#Browser_compatibility), most browsers support `fetch`.. All in all, I prefer using `fetch` over [`axios`](https://github.com/axios/axios), `XHR`, etc.. but since you specifically asked about `XHR`, that is how I answered.

If you did not want to `await` each response, you can do something like this:

```js
// basic XHR wrapper function for 'get'
function getXHR(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("get", url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        this.status == 200
          ? resolve(this.responseText)
          : reject(this.status);
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
  });
}

const ethElement = document.getElementById("eth");
const bcElement = document.getElementById("bc");
const lcElement = document.getElementById("lc");

// etherium
getXHR("https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/eth-usd")
  .then(eth => {
    // Can turn into JSON like this:
    //const ethJson = JSON.parse(eth);
    ethElement.innerHTML = eth;
  })

// bitcoin
getXHR("https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/btc-usd")
  .then(bc => {
    // Can turn into JSON like this:
    //const bcJson = JSON.parse(bc);
    bcElement.innerHTML = bc; 
  })

// litecoin
getXHR("https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/ltc-usd")
  .then(lc => {
    // Can turn into JSON like this:
    //const lcJson = JSON.parse(lc);
    lcElement.innerHTML = lc;  
  })
```

```html
<h1>eth:</h1>
<pre id="eth"></pre>
<h1>bc:</h1>
<pre id="bc"></pre>
<h1>litecoin:</h1>
<pre id="lc"></pre>
```

I have created the following demo to show you how to accomplish this using `async`/`await`:

```js
Init(); // call 'main' function

// basic XHR wrapper function for 'get'
function getXHR(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("get", url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        this.status == 200
          ? resolve(this.responseText)
          : reject(this.status);
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
  });
}

// "Main" function
async function Init() {
  const ethElement = document.getElementById("eth");
  const bcElement = document.getElementById("bc");
  const lcElement = document.getElementById("lc");

  // etherium
  const eth = await getXHR("https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/eth-usd");
  const ethJson = JSON.parse(eth);
  ethElement.innerHTML = ethJson.ticker.price + " " + ethJson.ticker.target;
  
  // bitcoin
  const bc = await getXHR("https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/btc-usd");
  const bcJson = JSON.parse(bc);
  bcElement.innerHTML = bcJson.ticker.price + " " + bcJson.ticker.target;
  
  // litecoin
  const lc = await getXHR("https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/ltc-usd");
  const lcJson = JSON.parse(lc);
  lcElement.innerHTML = lcJson.ticker.price + " " + lcJson.ticker.target;
}
```

```css
div h1,
div p {
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    line-height: 38px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>eth:</h1>
  <p id="eth"></p>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>btc:</h1>
  <p id="bc"></p>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>ltc:</h1>
  <p id="lc"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: This will wait for the completion of each request before starting the next, correct?

Comment: Yup.  If you watch very closely you can see each request come back and render in order.. I think it is easier to see it happen here, though: https://codepen.io/oze4/full/ExagQbW

Comment: OP has the requests running in parallel, no?

Comment: What do you mean? Are you asking me whether or not OPs example above is sending everything in parallel? Or are you asking me if OP wants to send everything in parallel?  OP mentioned he attempted to get `XHR` working with `async`/`await` but was not able to, hence this solution.. No matter how hard you try, nothing will be done "in parallel" - if you did not want to wait for each request to finish you can just do what my updated answer shows. From OP: `To note, I have worked with api before, but i used a await async function, but for some reason I couldn't get that to work`

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you well you can create a method for all cryptos and avoid repeting the same code. If you run the example below you will be able to see all cryptos and also it's easy to add new ones:

```js
const URL = 'https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/'
const cryptos = ['btc', 'ltc', 'eth']

cryptos.map(crypto => {
  fetch(`${URL}${crypto}-usd`)
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(({ ticker: { base, price } }) => console.log(`${base}: ${(+price).toFixed(2)}`))
})
```

We are using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) that is modern XHR. Hope this help.

Comment: This is awesome thanks for the response / answer. I am still trying to figure out how to take that data and apply it to each of my divs.

Comment: Keep in mind, this won't work in Internet Explorer. In my example I show how you can add the data to your `divs`...

Comment: You can use same cryto names for your `div` ids and use `document.querySelector` to select them and `textContent` to set the value

Comment: @Chumpocomon correct, it works with Edge, just not IE (any version of IE).. unless I am [reading this wrong](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why @ETHan ignored my answer explaining all of this, though... seems a little odd.